# That would be a good way to remember the definition of?

Tags: sentence-structure

> That would be a good way to remember the definition of?

I don't know how to make this sentence a question correctly.Should I say like this?
**That would be a good way to remember the definition of what?**

Actually, I saw this sentence somewhere and I don't know if there is another way to ask, or if it's correct.

> **Imagining a building shaped like a teapot would be a good way to remember the definition of?**

Comment: Your original is missing an object for *of*. And it's not clear whether you're asking for an effective way to remember something or asking whether a way you've already described is effective.

Comment: "**What** would be a good way to remember the definition of aldehyde dehydrogenase?"

Comment: *You are asking what?* (that's somewhat non-standard phrasing for *What are you asking?*).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ask a question with a yes/no answer, for example whether the statement above is true, then for sentences with "is", a verb tense modifier (will, have, had) or a modal (would, could, might, must...) you can make a question by simply swapping the subject and the verb, modifier or modal:

> That would be a good way ...

becomes

> Would that be a good way ...

If you are asking for suggestions about ways to remember something, you would replace the subject with a query pronoun:

> What would be a good way ...